# JQuery Mobile: Add additional class to JQM styled element

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I want to add a class to JQM's list divider `<li>`'s:

```html
<li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-bar-e ui-first-child">A</li>`
```

I have done this using JQuery within the HTML doc:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
                    $('.ui-li-divider').addClass('customClass');
                });
</script>
```

However, this does not seem to add the class to the element at all. If I inspect the element within my browser, I dont see `customClass` added to it.

Does anyone know the correct way of doing this without going into the guts of the JQM library?

(Note: the style sheet that has `cusomClass` is linked below the JQM style sheet)

Answer (score 0):

DEMO here, http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/5kfnT/4/ ...Try to comment on/off and see .addClass script to see effect.

Use .each() function.

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul .ui-li-divider").each( function () {
        $(this).addClass('customClass');
    });
});
```

## Your CSS

```
.customClass {
    background:red !important;
}
```

## Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Hmm...where have you positioned that script exactly?

Comment: Inside head section on main page. First, I linked css files, then js files, and finally, call custom js script.